# Sharedpreferences in activities - android

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, state

Please how to save state toggle button? i have MainActivity with load code and its correct. This is in public void onCreate.

```
SharedPreferences editor = getSharedPreferences("mymode", MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean tgpref = editor.getBoolean("tgpref", true);  //default is true

    if (tgpref == true) { //if (tgpref) may be enough, not sure
        chAppStat.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        chAppStat.setChecked(false);
    }
```

And save code in AppInfoAdapter, but in this class is incorrect MODE_PRIVATE.

```
public void onCheckedChanged( CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {     
    if(isChecked) {
        try {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true); // value to store
             editor.commit();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If is both in MainActivity is all corrent, but if is in two part is incorrent.Please give me some advice or example. Thanks

Comment: `getSharedPreferences` and `getPreferences` don't do the same thing. read the doc

Comment: yes my mistake but error with MODE_PRIVATE in appinfodata still is it

Comment: `getSharedPreferences("mymode", MODE_PRIVATE)` != `getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)`

Answer (score 1):

The key values that you are reading/saving are different:

reading "`tgpref`"

```
  boolean tgpref = editor.getBoolean("tgpref", true);  //default is true
```

and saving "`thpref`"

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("mymode",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("thpref", true); // value to store
                    editor.commit();
```

use the same key name "`tgpref`" in both!

**Update**:

Now your AppInfoAdapter must implement OnCheckedChangeListener

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener{
```

or set the listener to your checkbox:

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_checkbox );
myCheckBox .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            //0 = MODE_PRIVATE
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("mymode", 0).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("tgpref", isChecked );
    editor.commit();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: ok now your code is correct, your AppInfoAdapter extends OnCheckedChangeListener?

Comment: `chAppStat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(aListener); 

OnCheckedChangeListener aListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener ()`
I have a listener on my togglebutton

Comment: yes I have this right, what you write. error is still in `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("mymode",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();` more precisely in MODE_PRIVATE, other code is correct

Comment: see my answer, you need to set isChhecked in editor.putBoolean("tgpref", isChecked);

Comment: Yes i correct it thanks, but mode still incorrect: MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable, but is good syntax i mean.

Comment: Now i tried this: SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("mymode",MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
... and MODE_PRIVATE is correct but, getSharedPreference is incorrect what is wrong?

Comment: Read the documentation,  "Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation",  getSharedPreferences("mymode", 0);